# Get custom fields assigned to taxonomy

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

How to get custom fields assigned to taxonomy in Drupal 8. 
What I have done so far is:

```
$contact_countries = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('contact_country');
```

$contact_countries now holds taxonomies, I can get name of taxonomy and ID, but I also created custom field in taxonomy, how can I get it?

With this code

```
foreach($contact_countries as $contact_countrie) {
        $terms[] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($contact_countrie->tid);
        $variables['contact_countries'] = $terms;
    }
```

I'm getting object(Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term) with protected values. I can see my custom fields values there but can't access it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'created a custom field in taxonomy'? can you explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access fields using getFields() on the term object: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!src!Entity!Term.php/class/Term/8.2.x

Or you can use get(): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aget/8.2.x

Answer (score 5):

I done it like this:

```
$contact_countries = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('contact_country');

$terms = array();

foreach($contact_countries as $contact_countrie) {
    $terms[] = array(
        'contact_country' => $contact_countrie->name,
        'contact_phone' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($contact_countrie->tid)->get('field_phone')->getValue()[0]['value'],
        'contact_flag' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($contact_countrie->tid)->get('field_category_flag')->entity->uri->value,
    );
}
```

Here I have fields field_phone (text field) and field_category_flag (file field).

Answer (score 3):

I did it this way.

```
$countries = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('countries',0,NULL,TRUE);

/* Using First Country : $countries[0] */
$region = $countries[0]->get('field_region')->target_id;
$description = $countries[0]->get('field_description')->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_entity_lang = $entity->get('langcode')->value;
//version and so current revision
$translated_entity = $entity->getTranslation($current_entity_lang);
// if single value for the taxo
$value=$translated_entity->get('field_name')->referencedEntities()[0]->getName();
//else loop the values to get name
$values=$translated_entity->get('field_name')->referencedEntities();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal 9, the following code worked for me with a small-sized taxonomy.

```php
$vid = 'taxonomy_identifier';
$custom_field = 'field_identifier';
$output_array = [];

$terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadTree($vid, 0, 2, TRUE);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  foreach ($term->getFields(false) as $field) {
    if ($field->getName() == $custom_field) {
      $item_value = $field->getString();
      if ($item_value !== "") {
        $output_array[] = $item_value;
      }                
    }
  }
}

print_r($output_array);
```