# How to access taxonomy term field?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I added two fields to my vocabulary terms field management. How do I get these values? There is no fields like color or Image in my Taxonomy Term vocabulary dump.

How does Drupal 8 store these additional fields?

[image]

```
$terms = $this->taxonomyStorage->loadTree($vocabularyName);

//CAN ACCESS
$terms[0]->name

//CAN'T ACCESS
$terms[0]->color
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get custom fields assigned to taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232180/get-custom-fields-assigned-to-taxonomy)

Comment: See @GiorgosK's answer. You need to access it by its machine name which is field_color, not color

Answer (score 3):

Its similar to any other entity on Drupal 8

```
$name = $terms[0]->name;

//simple text field
$color = $terms[0]->field_color->value;

//multivalue field - get array of values
$color = $terms[0]->get('field_color')->getValue();

//entity reference field
$entity = $terms[0]->field_color->entity;

//image field 
$image = $terms[0]->get('field_image')->entity;
$image_uri = $image->getFileUri();

//get color entity id
$entity_id = $entity->id();
```

I think at least your **color** field is actually an entity reference

Comment: Unlucky i get error that it can't find nor field_color or color

Comment: the code above was tested and was working for a single TERM in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/template_preprocess_taxonomy_term/8.2.x ... I think you better post some sample code otherwise we can't really tell why your code is not working

Comment: The solution for me was:

Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($term->tid)->get('field_color')->color

Answer (score 0):

First of all, invoke the related class

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
```

and then try this code and just replace  VID with your machine

```
    $taxonomy_terms_vocabularies = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
         ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
         ->loadByProperties([ 
         'vid' => 'car_sub_type' 
     ]);
      $taxonomy_terms_vocabularies = array_keys($taxonomy_terms_vocabularies);         
      $taxonomy_terms_vocabularies_opt = [];
      foreach($taxonomy_terms_vocabularies as $key => $val){
        $term = Term::load($val); 
        $name = $term->getName();

          $taxonomy_terms_vocabularies_opt[] = array(
            'id' => $val, 
            'name' =>  $name
            'abc' =>   $term->get('field_machine_name')->value
          );      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the taxonomy is a entity reference field :

```
 $current_entity_lang = $entity->get('langcode')->value;
    //version and so current revision
    $translated_entity = $entity->getTranslation($current_entity_lang);
    // if single value for the taxo
    $value=$translated_entity->get('field_name')->referencedEntities()[0]->getName();
    //else loop the values to get name
    $values=$translated_entity->get('field_name')->referencedEntities();
```