# How to get taxonomy term field values

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have created vocabulary "Hospital" and created text and image fields like:

- Hospital Image: (machine name: field_hospital_image) // image field
- Hospital Contact: (machine name: field_hospital_contact_no_) // text field

My code is:

```
$vid = 'hospitals';
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $term_data[] = [
    'tid' => $term->tid,
    'tname' => $term->name,
    'image' => ...???..,    // image field
    'contact' => ...???..,  // text field
  ];
}
```

Please suggest namespace also.

I alsready tried :

```
'contact' => $term->get('field_hospital_contact_no_')->getValue(),
```

and

```
'contact' => $term->get('field_hospital_contact_no_')->value,
```

Errors:

> Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::get()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access taxonomy term field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258825/how-to-access-taxonomy-term-field)

Comment: Please also clarify what "Please suggest namespace also." means

Comment: namespace means like - use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

Comment: @GiorgosK - in my case its not working

Comment: @aazmi Than please change the question to reflect what you have tried perhaps with the errors that you get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Term object is not loaded with `loadTree` by default a basic php object is loaded instead.

You have to load the term object for each term using `$term_obj = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($term->tid);`

Your code should look like this

```
$vid = 'hospital';
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $term_obj = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($term->tid);
  $url = "";
  if(isset($term_obj->get('field_hospital_image')->entity)){
    $url = file_create_url($term_obj->get('field_hospital_image')->entity->getFileUri());
  }

  $term_data[] = [
    'tid' => $term->tid,
    'tname' => $term->name,
    'contact' => $term_obj->get('field_hospital_contact_no_')->value,
    'image_url' => $url,
  ];
}
```

**NOTE:** Alternatively you can also use `loadTree($vid, 0, NULL, TRUE)` to load the entities directly on the `$terms` array but perhaps it should be avoided on very large vocabularies.  More info on the [loadTree method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/8.2.x)

Comment: Its working for the "field_hospital_contact_no_" please provide solution for image :
Hospital Image: (machine name: field_hospital_image). I need image url

Comment: I tried for image like:

file_create_url($term_obj->get('field_hospital_image')->value->entity->getFileUri())

Comment: Try without `->value`

Comment: without `->value` it should work, revised my answer as well to get image_url

Comment: GiorgosK - I removed ->value got this error: "Error: Call to a member function getFileUri()".

Comment: @a-azmi The revised function above does exactly what you are trying to do, please use that, perhaps a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Hi @GiorgosK - its my mistake didnt uploaded any images with image field, thats why getting error, only default images was attached, now its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the code above accounts for it as well with the if statement

Comment: Thanks @ GiorgosK - i'll again come up to you with new problem :-)

Comment: how can i get multiple values from the same field?